# Synchronize 2 different iPhoto libraries

Tags: data-synchronization, photos.app

I need a tool/script to synchronize two different iPhoto libraries between two Mac books. By now I want to have common albums with my mother and myself.
Is there anything to do this automatically via Internet or local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that [iPhoto Library Manager](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/iplm/) might be of any use for you in that situation? It’s not free and I don’t have any personal experiences with this software but from what I’ve read it seems to work.

Hope it helps.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "Sync".

The general term means when two Libraries (A and B) are compared and files in Library A are copied to Library B, while files in Library B are also copied to Library A so that both Libraries are identical.

This is bi-directional copying and you cannot do this automatically with iPhoto. No Syncing software is capable of parsing the iPhoto Library in this manner. One or both of your Libraries will be damaged if you try this.

You can have uni-directional copying - files in Library A are copied to Library B - this is essentially backing up. Obviously you can also copy from Library B to Library A.

The nearest you can get to syncing is to use iPhoto Library Manager to move files/Albums/Events plus associated metadata between Libraries. This process cannot be automated.

Comment: Actually I have a family photo library and I want that this library will be stored both on my computer and on my parent's computer.

Comment: The key question is where is this Library updated from. If you always do updates, additions, edits etc on your machine then you can simply back your library up to the other machine.

Comment: I update it from my photocamera. I think copy and overwrite each time photolibrary manually is a little bit complicated and doesnt resolves photo libraries merge conflicts

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that badly. Do you always update the library on one machine. If you add to this library on either machine then what you want to do is impossible. If you always use the same machine for imports, then you can back up to the other. And, incidentally, do simple incremental back ups.